# Firebase: snapshot.val is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

So I am creating a small application using Express, Firebase and ReactJS.
I stubmled upon issue with Firebase snapshot.val

This part of code on express is serving my trips by ID and to get all. For all trips is working fine but when I try to go to the single trip it returns me this error

if I destructure it as an array:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function or its return value is not
>   iterable

If I destructure it as a object:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `trip` of 'undefined' or
>   'null'.

and I am totally baffled and can't find the solution.

Here is express part of the code:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');

const reference = () => firebase.database().ref('/trips')

exports.getSingle = async (id) => {
  //const snapshot = await reference()
  //  .orderByChild('id')
  //  .equalTo(id)
  //  .limitToFirst(1)
  //  .once('value');

  // const [trip] = snapshot.val();
  //  return trip
const snapshot = await reference()
    .orderByChild('id')
    .equalTo(parseInt(id, 10))
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .once('value');
  let trip = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function (tripSnapshot) {
    tripStorage = tripSnapshot.val();
    console.log(tripStorage);
    trip.push(tripStorage);
  });
  console.log(trip);
  return trip;
};

exports.getAll = async () => {
  const snapshot = await reference().once('value');

  return snapshot.val();
};
```

I am fetching trips in the frontend with:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/trips/get/" + this.state.id)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(trip =>
        this.setState({
          trip
        }, () => console.log("Trips fetched...", trip))
      );
  }
```

Controller for trips:

```
const express = require('express');

const route = express.Router();
const tripUtil = require('../utils/tripUtil');

route.get('/getAll', async (req, res) => {
  const trips = await tripUtil.getAll();

  res.json(trips);
});

route.get('/get/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const trip = await tripUtil.getSingle(id);

  if (trip) {
    res.json(trip);
  } else {
    res.status = 400;
    res.json({
      error: 'trip not found'
    });
  }
});

module.exports = route;
```

And maping properties from object like this:

```
 {this.state.trip.itinerary.days.map((day, i) => {
     return (
       <div key={i} className="trip-single-item__day">
          <div className="trip-single-item__day-header">
              <div className="trip-single-item__day-title">
                 {day.title}
              </div>
              <div className="trip-single-item__day-subtitle">
                 {day.subtitle}
              </div>
              <div className="trip-single-item__day-date">
                 {day.date}
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className="trip-single-item__day-body">
             <div className="trip-single-item__day-descritpion">
               {day.description}
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      );
  })}
```

Here is image of single trip [Single trip in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTm0q.jpg)

Any suggestions or directions? Thanks

Comment: why do you put the `trip` constant in square brackets? `const [trip] = snapshot.val();` Are you trying to access a property `trip` from the `snapshot.val()`, like `const { trip } = snapshot.val();`

Comment: If i place it like you suggest then I get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `trip` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
But I thought this is proper way to deconstruct the firebase object?

Comment: it was just a question, not a suggestion :) Can you edit your post and write the error: `it returns me this error and I am totally baffled`

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip. Why am I doing it? When I think a bit about it if it is stored as an object in firebase then there is no logic to access it via square brackets, but now I am even more confused why is the trip undefined.

Comment: Is the `id` property a nested property of the single `trip` object? If not, you can access it like this: `reference().child(id)`.once('value')`

Comment: Yea the id is a nested object of single `trip`.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue but without any success. I have some questions: do you call `firebase.initializeApp` before your request? And the other idea is to check your firebase rules. Do you have any specific rules or validations about the single trip object?

Comment: Yea i call `firebase.initializeApp`. Rules are also ok. If you look up there is code for fetching all trips I assume it wouldn't work if the `firebase.initializeApp` and rules aren't properly stored. I will attach the databse structure also in edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no more ideas. Are you sure that `getSingle` receives the correct `id` as a parameter? You can try to make your query more simple... start from  `await reference().once('value')`, then try with `await reference().child(0).once('value')` and check the results. Also, remove these square brackets, just `const trip = snapshot.val(); return trip;`

Comment: Put your code to a try catch first. Look at the error. I think you missed adding rules to firebase, so no permission error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase generally recommends against storing data as arrays in the Realtime Database (though some exceptions exist): https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

What I'm guessing is going on is that for some reason, your snapshot value is not being rendered as an array, but an object with numeric keys. One reason for this might be if the keys in Firebase are not strictly sequential, as Firebase will only render your data as an array if keys of the data start with 0 and there are no gaps.

Can you try this code to see if it works?

```
exports.getSingle = async (id) => {
  const snapshot = await reference()
    .orderByChild('id')
    .equalTo(id)
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .once('value');

  const queryResult = snapshot.val()
  console.log(queryResult) // Make note of the object shape here. Make sure there are actually results.

  const trip = Object.values(queryResult)[0]
  return trip;
};
```

Comment: It just returns queryResult as null so it seems like the reference to databse is not good. I also edited the controller code which serves by ID and all, maybe I am missing something there?

Comment: Seems like .orderByChild, .equalTo and limitToFirst are making an issue, and I can'T quite figure why.

Comment: The `:id` param you get from Express and pass into `getSingle` is most likely a string, and the `id` property of the trip in Firebase is a number. This might cause your `equalTo` query to fail, because it can't find an item with id === "1".

Try `equalTo(parseInt(id, 10))` and see if that solves it.

Comment: Yes this solved the part with the id which was obviously a string. But rather wierd thing is happening after i had to update the code for pushing the `snapshot.val()` into trip array and the pushed elements are rendered fine in JSON before it is pushed but when pushed nested items inside are displayed as [object Object].

Comment: Deeply nested JSON objects will often be displayed as [Object] or [object Object] when logged to the console using console.log. This is normal. You can try `console.log(JSON.stringify(trips, null, 2))` to serialize the object and pretty-print it out as a string.

Comment: It was bugging me and the I realized it after all, but I have manged to make it 2 things were missing the `equalTo(parseInt(id, 10))` and this code snippet for rendering trips https://pastebin.com/V6EgP3SB

Answer (score 0):

Might be an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

Handle your snapshot with then/catch

```
exports.getSingle = async (id) => {
  await reference()
    .orderByChild('id')
    .equalTo(id)
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .once('value').then(snapshot => {

         const [trip] = snapshot.val();
         return trip

        //  console.log(post.id)  if required
    })
};
```

Comment: Yes it gives, UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning I have edited the error. Was looking into firebase documentation and tried some variation like you have posted but still gives me the same error.